# Does It Matter Which Position Wordpress Plugin Functions Have?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Does it make a performance difference, either in perceived page load or server processing, which order the plugin functions are coded in?

For example, filters to add a body class, setting up Settings names, menu items, loading front end scripts or styles, and plugin page initialization? Certain ones impact the admin or front end display directly (adding a body class, for example) and others are processed strictly behind the scenes (like creating a table on activation).

I'm just curious what order, if any, has an impact perceived or real performance. *If this question is out of line, forgive me; I've looked and can't find an answer.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never experienced any performance issues in WP because of the position, so I would say that it should not matter. Some reasoning:

- if you have to calculate something before delivering content, and those tasks are independent, then total time will be the same regardless the order
- if tasks depend on each other, like you can preload and cache some data, then the order may have some influence on performance
- hooking to the wrong event and doing unnecessary work, like e.g. code which is needed only for admin panel executed during every request, that will be waste of resources and will cause some decline in performance
- theoretically, hooking to the event on too early phase of the page generation may cause that WP will have to do some work (like loading some data) twice.